# html page direct

Tags: javascript, html

hello i am new at html i am designing a quiz in html. this is example with 2 questions only.when i click a submit button i want to calculate marks show it in a alert box and then go to result.htm page .but when i click submit alert box shows answer but page is not redirected forward to result.htm.

my code is:

```
            <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <head>
                <title></title>
                <style type="text/css">
                   .d1
                   {
                       background-color:#FFFFCC;

                       } 

                    #Submit1
                    {
                        width: 67px;
                    }

                </style>
                <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

                    function Submit1_onclick() {
                        var i = 0;
                        var a = document.getElementById("Radio1");
                        if (a.checked == true) {
                            i++;
                        }
                        var b = document.getElementById("Radio8");
                        if (b.checked == true) {
                            i++;
                        }
                        alert(i);


            }

                </script>
            </head>
            <body>

                <p>
                    &nbsp;</p>
                    <form name="f1" method="post" action="d://result.htm">
                <div class="d1">
                Q1 What is your name ?
                <br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                   a <input id="Radio1" name="R1" type="radio" value="t" />
                    b <input id="Radio2" name="R1" type="radio" value="f" />
                      c <input id="Radio3" name="R1" type="radio" value="f" />
                      d <input id="Radio4" name="R1" type="radio" value="f" /></div>
                       <br />  <br />  <br />   
                        <div class="d1">
                Q1 What is your Id ?
                <br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                   1 <input id="Radio5" name="R11" type="radio" value="V1" />
                    2 <input id="Radio6" name="R11" type="radio" value="r1" />
                      3 <input id="Radio7" name="R11" type="radio" value="as1" />
                       4 <input id="Radio8" name="R11" type="radio" value="pop1" /></div>
                       <br />  <br />  <br /> 
                        <div class="d1">

                      <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit" onClick="return(Submit1_onclick())"/><br />  
                    <br />  <br />
                </form>


            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: try window.location = 'result.html';
after alert() in javascript code

Comment: tried bu its not working ..giving an error.. The HTTP verb POST used to access path '/WebSite2/result.htm' is not allowed.

Comment: yes. what you are doing does not make much sense. it redirected fine for me in chrome. you need to just start using some very basic tutorials on the web, of which there are plenty. you are clearly new. nothing wrong with that, but all this stuff is covered in many tutorials online.

Comment: What does the function `Submit1_onclick` return? You are using its return value in the `onClick` attribute of the `Submit` button, so it's important that you know what it returns.

Comment: im using visual studio 2010..

Comment: And another question. Are your quiz html file and your result.htm stored in the same location?

Comment: yeah its in same location in my D drive

Answer (score 0):

As the last line of your function call

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

                    function Submit1_onclick() {
                        var i = 0;
                        var a = document.getElementById("Radio1");
                        if (a.checked == true) {
                            i++;
                        }
                        var b = document.getElementById("Radio8");
                        if (b.checked == true) {
                            i++;
                        }
                        alert(i);
                        location.href="result.htm";

            }

                </script>
```

This will redirect the page

Comment: can you change the button click to  <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit" onClick="Submit1_onclick();"/>

Answer (score 0):

Change your markup to this:

```
<input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit" onclick="Submit1_onclick();"/>
```

and add this to your javascript:

```
function Submit1_onclick() {
    ...
    alert(i);
    return true;
}
```

Returning true from an event handler will tell the browser to continue the default behavior (in this case, submit the form).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're trying to submit a POST between two static files in an IIS server, which you can't do. You can change the files to `.aspx` and it should work as expected.